# Rails with NGINX Reverse proxy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, production-environment

I'm trying to run on production a Rails 6 application with Nginx (1.21) as a reverse proxy (both running on a dedicated Docker container). I have already done it for other 2 applications and as far as I know, I'm using the same setup but this time I get a

> Network Protocol Error
>
> An error occurred during a connection to mysite.com.

The issue seems to be specific with HTTPS since I'm able to connect over HTTP (I have enabled http while troubleshooting this issue. On production, I plan to redirect HTTP over HTTPS).

Here my nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name mysite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name mysite.com;

  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 1d;
  ssl_session_cache shared:MySSL:10m;
  ssl_session_tickets off;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location / {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY" always;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    http2_push_preload on;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
  }
}
```

and docker compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  ...
  
  app:
    container_name: 'app'
    image: ghcr.io/lorem/railsapp
    entrypoint: ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "/usr/bin/supervisord"]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: app.env
    networks:
      - net
    restart: unless-stopped

  proxy:
    container_name: 'nginx'
    image: nginx:1.21.4-alpine
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    volumes:
      - /usr/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /usr/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/privkey.pem
      - /usr/nginx/dhparam-2048.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - net
    restart: unless-stopped

    ...
```

When I point the browser to `mysite.com` I can see the following log entries in nginx

```
89.207.121.108 - - [05/Jan/2022:15:28:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 103 3456 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0" "-"
```

and rails

```
I, [2022-01-05T15:28:33.143912 #22]  INFO -- : [cdb55cd4-bfa6-4135-9d70-d6c578c794a0] Started GET "/" for 188.0.0.4 at 2022-01-05 15:28:33 +0000
I, [2022-01-05T15:28:33.144964 #22]  INFO -- : [cdb55cd4-bfa6-4135-9d70-d6c578c794a0] Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
D, [2022-01-05T15:28:33.150207 #22] DEBUG -- : [cdb55cd4-bfa6-4135-9d70-d6c578c794a0]   Rendering layout layouts/base.html.erb
D, [2022-01-05T15:28:33.150418 #22] DEBUG -- : [cdb55cd4-bfa6-4135-9d70-d6c578c794a0]   Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/base
```

It's 2 days I'm dealing with this and I'm not able to figure out what's wrong.
Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: After further investigation, the issue seems to be connected to HTTP/2.
Updating the Nginx configuration from `listen 443 ssl http2;` to `listen 443 ssl;` seems to have fixed the issue.